# Error launching android studio

Tags: java, android, jvm, android-studio

I want to install and run Android Studio on my Windows 8 Pro 64-bit.
I can install, but when I running the app, this error appears:

> Failed to load JVM DLL C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre. If you
>   already have a 64-bit JDK installed, define a JAVA_HOMEvariable in
>   Computer > System Properties > System Settings > Enviroment Variables.

I define a JAVA_HOME on system variable 3 times with this values:

First time:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25
```

Second time:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25 ; C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin
```

And third time:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25 ; C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin ; C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre
```

But I have same problem in 3 states.

Comment: Use Eclipse. Android Studio has NEVER worked for me. Always run into the module name nonsense. Seriously. Search for the Android Eclipse download. Download it, run it, code it. :)

Answer (score 6):

Go to **system properties** then **Advanced system settings**
Cick bellow **Enviroment variables**
in system variables click **New** and input **variable name** JAVA_HOME and variable value java path, *(example: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0)*

Comment: In my case when I add last "backslash", then it just works. C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\

Answer (score 5):

run studio64.exe instead of studio.exe, had same problem and this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I am using Windows Pro 8 too, here is my JAVA_HOME setting:

> JAVA_HOME=c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_15

What I can suggest is the following:
If android-studio installed successfully and cannot launch it, 
go to your user profile folder :

> cd %USERPROFILE%
>
> delete ".AndroidStudioPreview"

open a new command line terminal:

> set JAVA_HOME

make sure that the path returned is set to the proper java jdk directory. 
If this does not show anything this means that your environment variable is not available.

Then launch android studio out of the command line.

If the problem persists try to install a new jdk side by side and point to the new jdk with JAVA_HOME.

Comment: I did that, but I still have the same problem

Comment: have you tried another 64 bit jdk and point your JAVA_HOME to it ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the installation folder in

C:\Program Files
or
C:\Program Files(X86)

If its in Program Files directory set the environment variable as

C:\Program Files\jdk_name

else

C:\Program Files(X86)\jdk_name

Answer (score 0):

Change your most recent JDK folder name to the version the application is looking for. Example:

Go to:

`C:\Program Files\Java`

and rename the folder with most recent JDK version from `\jdk1.7.0_XX` to `\jdk1.7.0_25`

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

Define a environment variable JAVA_HOME pointing to the JDK location (without BIN folder), like this:

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101;
```

(Set it in system and local variable)

After that, add

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin
```

to PATH variable (both in system and local settings)

Be sure to point to **JDK installation directory, not JRE directory**.

Then restart your computer.

Answer (score 0):

If you install android studio x64 you should have java sdk x64 installed if not you can install it and try again