# Error Lunching Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've installed the latest Android studio yesterday, after a hard time waiting for everything to download, I finally could run it. but with a very bad performance and the PC( thinkpad T430 i5 4g windows10-64 java64) was slowed down drastically.Followed a tutorial on stackoverflow.it worked , but when I tried to relaunch it again it gives me this error:[Failed to create JVM error: -6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUnB8.jpg)

I've set the JAVA_HOME again

Comment: Try this --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19728702/error-launching-android-studio

Comment: no answer was resolving the problem on that topic @SalmanS

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio is slow and its even more slow at the start. Maybe it was actually okay at first? Also, you might need to make sure the envir. variables are pointing at the actual locations. Also, you could post the tutorial you have followed so we can help you better.

Comment: here's the tutorial:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30817871/android-studio-is-slow-how-to-speed-up      I've just deleted the folder C:\Users\Enigman\.AndroidStudio3.1 Now it's working but the built of a single empty project takes too long

Answer (score 0):

1. First goto This pc -> documents
2. delete AndroidStudio folder
3. start android studio

Hope this will fix your issue

Comment: This folder doesn't exist on my PC.